# If $X_n\to0$ in probability then $X_n/r_n\to0$ in probability, for some $r_n\to0$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Suppose that a sequence of positive random variables $X_n$ is such that for all $\epsilon >0$, $P(X_n>\epsilon)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, that is $X_n$ converges in probability to $0$, or equivalently $X_n = o_p(1)$. 
>   Does this imply that there must exist a non-random sequence $r_n$ such that $X_n = o_p(r_n)$ where $r_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

My intuition suggests that this must be right, by the following argument: if there exists no sequence $r_{n}$ such that the above holds, then $X_n$ cannot converge in probability to zero.

Can anyone verify my intuition or provide a counterexample?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean with the notation $o_p(r_n)$ or with "deterministic" sequence $r_n$. If you mean that it exists a sequence $r_n$ such that $X_{r_n}$ converges almost surely to $0$, then you're right

Comment: If $X_n = o_p(r_n)$ then for all $\epsilon >0$, $P(X_n/r_n > \epsilon) \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, I want to show that there exists an $r_n$ such that this holds true given that $X_n = o_p(1)$.

Comment: Well if you mean that any sequence such that $r_n \le 1$ would work, wouldn't it?

Comment: Not correct, you can create a sequence such that $P(X_n/n > \epsilon) \rightarrow 0$, but $P(X_n/n^2 > \epsilon) > 0$ for $n$ large enough, so just because $X_n = o_p(1)$ doesn't imply that $X_n$ converges to zero arbitrarily fast.

Comment: And when did I write that? I'm not following you

Comment: Explain to me what you mean by any sequence $r_n \leq 1$, because we have no information at which the rate $X_n$ converges in probability to zero. If you are saying any sequence such that $r_n \leq 1$ and $r_n \rightarrow 0$, then I believe that is incorrect, but I could be misinterpreting you.

Comment: Ah I see the what you mean, I should have said $P(nX_n > \epsilon) \rightarrow 0$ and $P(n^2 X_n > \epsilon)\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: My point was that if $r_n \le 1$ then $P(X_n / r_n > \varepsilon) \le P(X_n > \varepsilon) \to 0$ which implies $P(X_n / r_n > \varepsilon) \to 0$; your example would correspond to $r_n = n$ which is not $\le 1$. The inequality comes from the fact that $\{\omega: X_n(\omega) > r_n \varepsilon\} \subset \{\omega: X_n(\omega) > \varepsilon\}$

Comment: Yes - read the above comments, I mean to have said that $X_n = o_p(n^{-1})$ implies $P(nX_n > \epsilon)\rightarrow 0$ which doesn't necessarily mean that $X_n = o_p(n^{-2})$.

Comment: Can you provide a counter example then? it seems to be that my short proof is correct and if $r_n \le 1$ (or even better $r_n \to 0$) then it should hold

Comment: The implication that if $X_n=o_P(1)$ then there exists some (deterministic) sequence $(r_n)$ such that $r_n\to0$ and $X_n=o_P(r_n)$, follows from the classical *diagonal argument*, which is as follows. For every $k$, $P(X_n>1/3^k)\to0$ when $n\to\infty$ hence there exists some finite $N_k$ such that $P(X_n>1/3^k)<1/k$ for every $n\geqslant N_k$. Assume without loss of generality that $(N_k)$ is increasing and define $r_n=1/2^k$ for every $N_k\leqslant n<N_{k+1}$. Then, ...

Comment: ... for every $\epsilon>0$, choose $k(\epsilon)$ such that $\epsilon/2^{k(\epsilon)}>1/3^{k(\epsilon)}$. Then, for every $n\geqslant N_{k(\epsilon)}$, one knows that $n\geqslant N_k$ for some $k\geqslant k(\epsilon)$ hence $P(X_n>r_n\epsilon)\leqslant1/k$, qed.

Comment: Thanks @Did, I have a concern though, hopefully you can clarify for me, I have been able to arrive at the conclusion that $P(X_n > \epsilon/2^{k(\epsilon)}) \leq 1/k(\epsilon)$ for $n\geq N_k$, where $k\geq k(\epsilon)$. How do you arrive at the conclusion that $P(X_n>r_n\epsilon) \leq 1/k$ for $n$ large enough?

Comment: ok sorry, I see it now - thanks